# WiX in Jenkins: candle.exe : error CNDL0103 : The system cannot find the file Product_PHP.wxs' with type 'Source'

Tags: jenkins, wix, jenkins-plugins, wix3

We have a product for which a hired freelancer made a WiX project to build installers.
I am new to WiX, and I'm trying to automate the process of installer building.

When I build the project in Visual Studio, everything is okay.

When I'm trying to build the project in Jenkins, I'm getting the following output:

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Installer
[wix] Enable Debug: true
[wix] Detecting environment variables...
[wix] Found sources: 3
[wix] Initializing tools...
[wix] Environment variables are not automatically added as parameters.
[wix] Environment variables are not automatically added as parameters.
[wix] Compiler found.
[wix] Linker found.
[wix] Starting compile process...
[wix] adding source file: C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Installer\WiXInstaller\Product_PHP.wxs
[wix] adding source file: C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Installer\WiXInstaller\Product_Passwork.wxs
[wix] adding source file: C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Installer\WiXInstaller\WiXBootstrapper.wxs
[wix] Executing command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\candle.exe" -arch x64 -ext WixBalExtension -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixUtilExtension -ext WixDependencyExtension -ext WixFirewallExtension -ext WixIIsExtension -nologo -out C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Installer\WiXInstaller\Product_PHP.wixobj C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Installer\WiXInstaller\Product_PHP.wxs C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Installer\WiXInstaller\Product_Passwork.wxs C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Installer\WiXInstaller\WiXBootstrapper.wxs
[Installer] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\candle.exe" -arch x64 -ext WixBalExtension -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixUtilExtension -ext WixDependencyExtension -ext WixFirewallExtension -ext WixIIsExtension -nologo -out C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Installer\WiXInstaller\Product_PHP.wixobj C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Installer\WiXInstaller\Product_PHP.wxs C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Installer\WiXInstaller\Product_Passwork.wxs C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Installer\WiXInstaller\WiXBootstrapper.wxs
candle.exe : error CNDL0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Installer\WiXInstaller\Product_PHP.wxs' with type 'Source'.
[wix] Compiling failed.
[wix] Compiling failed.
Build step 'WIX Toolset' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Here is the file:
[Screenshot of the Windows explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD1nY.png)

And here is the settings of the WiX plugin in Jenkins:
[Jenkins WiX plugin settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG2Oh.png)

It looks like that I can't do something to change something as the WiX settings in  Jenkins are very limited.

Please, tell me what I'm doing wrong. If you need additional information — just let me know.

Comment: It is somewhat strange that the workspace is located in the profile folder of the local system user. Could be a permissions issue. Try to configure Jenkins to use a different folder like "c:\workspace".

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem was in the dot containing in the path. It splits the path, and the resulting path was C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.